# React-Native-Navigation - Fire an event on tab change

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am working in react-native with **react-native-navigation**. And i am having an issue related to tab events.

**I want to load data when a specific tab is selected.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As for RNN v1.1.x, there are two way to listen to tab clicks.

## Set a Tab Click Listener

```
import {
  NativeAppEventEmitter,
  DeviceEventEmitter,
  Platform
} from 'react-native';

let eventSubscription;

export class TabSelectionListener {
  register() {
    this.unregister();
    eventSubscription = this.getEventEmitter().addListener('bottomTabSelected', (event) => {
      const currentTab = biLabels[event.unselectedTabIndex];
      const targetTab = biLabels[event.selectedTabIndex];
      console.log(`Switching tab from ${currentTab} to ${targetTab}`)
      if (targetTab === dataTab) {
        // load data now
      }
    });
  }

  unregister() {
    if (eventSubscription) {
      eventSubscription.remove();
    }
  }

  getEventEmitter() {
    return Platform.OS === 'android' ? DeviceEventEmitter : NativeAppEventEmitter;
  }
}
```

## Listen to tab click in the root screen displayed in the tab

From the [docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=listening-to-tab-selected-events)

```
class ExampleScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));
  }

  onNavigatorEvent(event) {
    if (event.id === 'bottomTabSelected') {
      console.log('Tab selected!');
    }
    if (event.id === 'bottomTabReselected') {
      console.log('Tab reselected!');
    }
  }
}
```

## Listen to screen visibility change

from the [docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=screen-visibility):

```
export default class ExampleScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));
  }
  onNavigatorEvent(event) {
    if (event.id === 'willAppear') {
       // Load data now
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by using reducer just create a method in which you have to check Scene Key and if it is your desired tab you can perform your action there... and call this function in your Router as props. This is the same work I done for my tab app.

```
    reducerCreate = params => {
      const defaultReducer = new Reducer(params);
       return (state, action) => {
         switch(action.type){
            case ActionConst.JUMP:
                if(action.key ==="Tab1") {
                    //Action for Tab1.
                }
                else if(action.key ==="Tab2" ) {
                    //Action for Tab2.
                }
        }
        return defaultReducer(state, action);
    };
};

      <Router
                createReducer={this.reducerCreate}
                navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar}
                titleStyle={styles.navBarTitle}
            >

               <Scene initial 
                  style={{paddingTop: 0}}
                  key="home"
                  component={Home}
                  >
                    <Scene 
                        key="Tab1"
                        component={Tab1View}
                     />
                    <Scene 
                        key="Tab2"
                        component={Tab2View}
                    />
            </Scene>
  </Router>
```